# Data masking in postgres community edition

Tags: postgresql-9.5, data-masking

Looking for data masking solution for my postgres community edition. Your suggestion to it is appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.5 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.

Comment: Can't we do data masking in Postgres 9.5

Comment: you can use some third party product like DataSunrise Proxy for masking purpose